# Zip archives in node.js

Tags: node.js, zip

I want to create a zip archive and unzip it in node.js.

I can't find any node implementation.

Comment: https://github.com/pquerna/node-archive

Comment: node-archive is not very developer friendly, the documentation is very poor and the examples do not cover actually creating a ZIP, only reading an existing one.

Comment: Nice find. I only need to read a zip, so this should be ok... i hope

Answer (score 29):

I ended up doing it like this (I'm using Express). I'm creating a ZIP that contains all the files on a given directory (SCRIPTS_PATH).

I've only tested this on Mac OS X Lion, but I guess it'll work just fine on Linux and Windows with Cygwin installed.

```js
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
app.get('/scripts/archive', function(req, res) {
    // Options -r recursive -j ignore directory info - redirect to stdout
    var zip = spawn('zip', ['-rj', '-', SCRIPTS_PATH]);

    res.contentType('zip');

    // Keep writing stdout to res
    zip.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        res.write(data);
    });

    zip.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        // Uncomment to see the files being added
        // console.log('zip stderr: ' + data);
    });

    // End the response on zip exit
    zip.on('exit', function (code) {
        if(code !== 0) {
            res.statusCode = 500;
            console.log('zip process exited with code ' + code);
            res.end();
        } else {
            res.end();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Confirming this works on linux no problem, node 0.4.9, with zip installed. Thanks for the code Eliseo, sure saved me some time I bet.

Comment: Can anybody confirm this will work on Windows without Cygwin?

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Just a single question - how could I set the archive's name which the browser downloads? Tried to set content-disposition header but this didn't helped.

Comment: What is the "app" variable? Is that an http process?

Comment: "app" is an HTTP app created with Express JS

Comment: This answer is pushing the envelope of what I'd call "in node.js" and it will only work when you have these specific binaries installed. Personally, I'm looking for a node.js library that can handle this work without spawning a subprocess.

Answer (score 29):

node-core has built in zip features: http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html

Use them:

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
var gzip = zlib.createGzip();
var fs = require('fs');
var inp = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');
var out = fs.createWriteStream('input.txt.gz');

inp.pipe(gzip).pipe(out);
```

Comment: but it's not .zip. i hope they really have a archiving module for .zip built in the core

Comment: What is the advantage of using zip over gzip?

Comment: @dopatraman [Basically gzip compresses the files as a whole whereas zip compresses each file separately](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-zip-and-gzip/). There are different cases where one is preferred over the other.

Comment: Is there an asynchronous way to do this?

Comment: can we zip folder using this built-in module?

Answer (score 10):

You can try [node-zip](https://github.com/daraosn/node-zip) npm module.

It ports JSZip to node, to compress/uncompress zip files.

Comment: Since you look to be the author: What is the purpose of your module? As far as I can see, it's just a wrapper for JsZip: `var fs = require('fs');
var JSZip = require('jszip');

global.JSZip = JSZip;
module.exports = function(data, options) { return new JSZip(data, options) };` I have a problem with JsZip in that it's not async, does your module solve the issue?

Comment: From the issue tracker https://github.com/daraosn/node-zip/issues/12: "This project is more than 2 years old, by that time I couldn't use JSZip directly on a node application, the same way I'd do it on a front-end app. node-zip just wraps around a global JSZip variable to be used directly in the app and also includes a CLI. So yeah, it's just a port and I'm maintaining it for legacy reasons because lots of projects are using it. Feel free to use JSZip directly."

Answer (score 7):

You can use [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) module, it was very helpful for me, here is an example:

```
var Archiver = require('archiver'),
    fs = require('fs');
app.get('download-zip-file', function(req, res){    
    var archive = Archiver('zip');
    archive.on('error', function(err) {
        res.status(500).send({error: err.message});
    });
    //on stream closed we can end the request
    res.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Archive wrote %d bytes', archive.pointer());
        return res.status(200).send('OK').end();
    });
    //set the archive name
    res.attachment('file-txt.zip');
    //this is the streaming magic
    archive.pipe(res);
    archive.append(fs.createReadStream('mydir/file.txt'), {name:'file.txt'});
    //you can add a directory using directory function
    //archive.directory(dirPath, false);
    archive.finalize();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need unzip, [node-zipfile](https://github.com/springmeyer/node-zipfile) looks to be less heavy-weight than [node-archive](https://github.com/pquerna/node-archive). It definitely has a smaller learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

[adm-zip](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip)

It's a javascript-only library for reading, creating and modifying zip archives in memory.

It looks nice, but it is a little buggy. I had some trouble unzipping a text file.

Comment: Yes it does appear buggy to me as well, crc errors on large files zipped up and checked with 7zip

Comment: This package has [irresponsible dependency versioning](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/issues/121#issuecomment-73559704) and is causing mayhem as we speak. Do not use it.

Comment: The comment made by @lazd is now recitified, and adm-zip is not causing mayhem any more...

Comment: @holroy that's correct, they removed the offending module and all is well again.

Comment: adm-zip still has issues in that the compression it uses creates problematic zip archives. See this github issue: https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/issues/102

Comment: For my use case the API and zero-dependency of adm-zip would fit perfectly but sadly it is giving me corrupted files. I'm using jszip instead.

Comment: I use adm-zip without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have used 'archiver' for zipping files. Here is one of the Stackoverflow link which shows how to use it, [Stackoverflow link for zipping files with archiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142129/how-to-convert-multiple-files-to-compressed-zip-file-using-node-js/26423629#26423629)

Answer (score 1):

I've found it easiest to roll my own wrapper around 7-zip, but you could just as easily use zip or whatever command line zip tool is available in your runtime environment. This particular module just does one thing: zip a directory.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (directory, zipfile, log) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!log) log = console;

    try {
      const zipArgs = ['a', zipfile, path.join(directory, '*')];
      log.info('zip args', zipArgs);
      const zipProcess = spawn('7z', zipArgs);
      zipProcess.stdout.on('data', message => {
        // received a message sent from the 7z process
        log.info(message.toString());
      });

      // end the input stream and allow the process to exit
      zipProcess.on('error', (err) => {
        log.error('err contains: ' + err);
        throw err;
      });

      zipProcess.on('close', (code) => {
        log.info('The 7z exit code was: ' + code);
        if (code != 0) throw '7zip exited with an error'; // throw and let the handler below log it
        else {
          log.info('7zip complete');
          return resolve();
        }
      });
    }
    catch(err) {
      return reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Use it like this, assuming you've saved the above code into `zipdir.js`. The third `log` param is optional. Use it if you have a custom logger. Or delete my obnoxious log statements entirely.

```
const zipdir = require('./zipdir');

(async () => {
  await zipdir('/path/to/my/directory', '/path/to/file.zip');
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use/learn a library, you could [use node to control the zip commandline tools by executing child processes](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.6/api/child_processes.html)

Though I'd recommend learning a library like the one mentioned by Emmerman

Answer (score -5):

You can use the [edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge) module that supports interop between node.js and .NET in-process, and then call into .NET framework's ZipFile class which allows you to manipulate ZIP archives. Here is a [complete example of creating a ZIP package using edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/blob/master/samples/207_zip.js). Also check out the [unzip example using edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/blob/master/samples/207_unzip.js).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. How is using a library to run .NET code to do your unzipping a *node* implementation?

Comment: Don't you think including all of .NET, hosted in process, is a dramatic increase in complexity for just zipping and unzipping files?

Comment: See my response below for how to use node-core's built in modules to zip files.