# Stream multiple files in a simple request with node.js

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, coffeescript

I am trying to stream multiple video files in a single request with a node.js application written in coffescript. Here is my code:

```
express = require 'express'

app = express.createServer(
  express.compiler(src: __dirname + '/client', enable: ['coffeescript']),
  #express.static(__dirname + '/client'),
  express.errorHandler dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true
)

app.get('/video/:number', (req, res) ->
  console.log 'sending'
  res.sendfile("sample#{req.params.number}.webm")
)

port = 3000
app.listen port
```

So far I manage to send a single file and I can point to any video file which name is formatted like `sample<number>.webm`. My goal is to be able to send all files inside a folder with that same name format but with a single request, meaning that when the users point the browser to `http://localhost:3000` for example, videos would be shown as if they were one single video.

Answer (score 2):

You [can't just concatenate WebM files](https://groups.google.com/a/webmproject.org/group/webm-discuss/browse_thread/thread/8fa0a6e45e4fd985?pli=1), so you will have to either:

1. Build one big file by concatenating all the videos,
2. Run them through a pipeline which concatenates the videos, or
3. Send a list of video names and sequentially poll the videos in javascript.

I'd pick number 3, it seems simple and bandwidth frugal.

Comment: The first two options can't really be achieved instantaneously as it's supposed to be done on a get request. Videos concatenation (e.g.  with something like `ffmpeg`) would take some decent time, so concatenated videos should be already precached. So basically there's only a third option or an option of creating a quite more complex system of preparing concatenated videos on upload.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov I already tried having a player with playlist support and fetching the playlist with an ajax request but the approach was discarded because videos did not play fluently; it was obvious that there were multiple files which is not the idea. Thanks for your ansmer

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: While I would recommend not concatenating the videos, I'm certain you could start an ffmpeg pipeline and start serving the file immediately. Node is pretty good for stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not zip all the video files on server side and send back a zip archive.. something like this..

[Zip archives in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754153/zip-archives-in-node-js)

Comment: Zipping the files on server side, send them to the client and unzip them would result in extra processing time and larger bandwidth use so it is not a possibility for this particular case. Thanks for your answer