# NodeJS Zip Support on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express

I'm looking to be able to zip a file on heroku and send it back to the client. Locally, during development I used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6837589/5210). It worked great. However, if you do this on heroku you'll get an error:

```
zip stderr: execvp(): No such file or directory
```

Looks like zip is not supported on Heroku's instances. Therefore I went to try [node-native-zip](https://github.com/janjongboom/node-native-zip) and this worked locally, but the file is corrupt when I download and I cannot get it to upen via the OSX Utility. However, it opens via the CLI with unzip ([known issue](https://github.com/janjongboom/node-native-zip/issues/9)).

So the question is, if I want to zip a folder on heroku and send it to the user, what npm module should I use? Or is there something thats better or simpler that I'm not thinking of? The end result I'm after is the ability to deliver a folder to the end user via the browser, easily. Zip seemed like the best method. But the libraries out there don't seem to cut it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [node-native-zip](https://github.com/donnfelker/node-native-zip) to solve my zipping issues on Heroku and abandoned the approach above and it worked fine.