# Generate a password protected ZIP file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, password-protection

I need to create a ZIP file in node.js, protected by a password.

I am using "node-zip" module, that unfortunately doesn't support password protection:

```
var zip = new require('node-zip')();
zip.file('test.file', 'hello there');
var data = zip.generate({base64:false,compression:'DEFLATE'});
```

Looking other node modules to create ZIP files, I haven't found any that support password protection.

Comment: Google "create zip node js"? Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754153/zip-archives-in-node-js After reading the first link it seems spawning a command line tool is the way to go.

Comment: I found [a plugin](https://github.com/ksoichiro/node-archiver-zip-encryptable) for node-archiver to create encrypted zip. It works on stream as well. But I didn't test it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you work on linux then you can do it with the help of zip (command line utility in most linux distributions). Just include the following in you app.

```
spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
zip = spawn('zip',['-P', 'password' , 'archive.zip', 'complete path to archive file']);
zip .on('exit', function(code) {
...// Do something with zipfile archive.zip
...// which will be in same location as file/folder given
});
```

If you want to zip a folder just put another argument '-r', before the folder path instead of file path.

Remember this spawns separate thread, from main process, so it is non blocking. For more info on `child_process` look here http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: Your solutions seems to be ok, but I need to create the file "on the fly", I mean the files don't exist in the file system (they contain sensitive data).
As fas as i know, you cannot pass zip command a file structure with content, right?

Comment: You mean to compress whatever data you have in variable, not on file. Zip also accepts a single dash ("-") as the name of a file to be compressed, in which case it will read the file from standard input. You can just write the file contents into stdin of spawned child process zip.stdin.write(data); Look for stdin examples on the same page. http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin

Comment: I need to write two files inside the zip, with concrete names (I tried with "-" as filename, but the name remains "-" inside the zip file).
I am afraid I must use a temporary directory to unzip the files I created with node-zip, and then compress again with zip command using password :(

Answer (score 14):

For anyone who ends up here like I did, I tried several packages in node but ended up using this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/minizip-asm.js

It supports passwords (using AES) and is really easy to use.  I'm surprised it doesn't have that many downloads given that it's the only one I found supporting passwords.

Comment: Doesn't have type declaration for typescript

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and couldn't find the package to do it, so I've written one on my own, as a plugin to [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) package. Pure JS, no external zip software needed.

Here it is - https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver-zip-encrypted. 
Supports both legacy Zip 2.0 encryption and AES-256 encryption from WinZip.

Comment: While archiver has typescript type declarations, archiver-zip-encrypted doesn't and has to be be manually added, look at open issue: https://github.com/artem-karpenko/archiver-zip-encrypted/issues/31

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm using (I don't know a better way to do it) is:

```
var contenido1 = 'contenido super secreto';
var contenido2 = 'otro contenido';
var password = 'pass';
var nombreFichero = 'fichero'

var nodezip = new require('node-zip')();
var fs = require("fs");
nodezip.file('test1.txt', contenido1);
nodezip.file('test2.txt', contenido2);
var data = nodezip.generate({base64:false,compression:'DEFLATE'});
fs.writeFile(nombreFichero + '.zip', data, 'binary');

var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('unzip ' + nombreFichero + '.zip -d ' + nombreFichero +
             ' && zip -junk-paths --password ' + password + ' ' + nombreFichero + '-p.zip ' + nombreFichero + '/*' +
             ' && rm -rf ' + nombreFichero + ' && rm -f ' + nombreFichero + '.zip',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

It generates a temporary zip file (without password), and then with several commands, upzip, zip with password and remove temporary files.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking out to create password protected zip file in NextJS (compatible with NodeJS as well) server side, please refer this :

You can place this code under api folder in NextJS

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import formidable from 'formidable';
import { join } from 'path';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

      form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error parsing form data:', err);
          res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to parse form data' });
          reject(err);
          return;
        }

        const password: string = fields.password.toString();
        const myFile = fields.myFile;

        if (!myFile) {
          res.status(400).json({ error: 'File not found in request' });
          return;
        }

        // Decode the Base64 string into a buffer
        const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(Array.isArray(myFile) ? myFile[0] : myFile, 'base64');

        // Save the file buffer to a temporary file
        const tempFilePath = join(process.cwd(), 'zippedFiles', 'temp_file');
        require('fs').writeFileSync(tempFilePath, fileBuffer);

        // Create a password-protected zip using the `zip` command with `-j` flag
        // `-j` flag will store just the file, not the directories
        const zipFilePath = join(process.cwd(), 'zippedFiles', 'protected.zip');
        const zipProcess = spawn('zip', ['-j', '-P', password, zipFilePath, tempFilePath]);

        zipProcess.on('exit', (code) => {
          if (code === 0) {
            // Zip file creation successful
            res.status(200).json({ zipPath: 'protected.zip' });
            resolve();
          } else {
            // Zip file creation failed
            console.error('Error creating password-protected zip file');
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to create zip file' });
            reject(new Error('Failed to create zip file'));
          }

          // Delete the temporary file
          require('fs').unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error generating password-protected zip:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to generate zip file' });
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```

I am also providing sample client side code for end to end implementation

```
import axios from 'axios';

const createPasswordProtectedZip = async (selectedFile: File, password: string) => {

  let data = undefined
  const base64Data = await readFileAsBase64(selectedFile);

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('myFile', base64Data);
  formData.append('password', password);


  data = await axios.post('/api/download-zip', formData).then((res: any) => {
    console.log('File response:', res.data);
    return res.data
  }).catch((e: any) => {
    console.log('File error:', e);
    return undefined
  });

  return data

};

const readFileAsBase64 = (file: File) => {
  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = () => {
      const result = reader.result;
      if (typeof result === 'string') {
        const base64Data = result.split(',')[1];
        if (base64Data) {
          resolve(base64Data);
        } else {
          reject(new Error('Failed to read the file.'));
        }
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Failed to read the file.'));
      }
    };

    reader.onerror = (error) => {
      reject(error);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
};
export default createPasswordProtectedZip;
```

Please note that I am using typescript.