# how to extract password-protected zip in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, zip, unzip

```
const unzipper = require("unzipper");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function test() {
  const file = "old.zip";
  const password = "abc";
  const directory = await unzipper.Open.file(file);
  console.log("password", password);
  const extracted = await directory.files[0].buffer(password);
  fs.writeFileSync("extracted/", extracted);
}
test();
```

I have two files, `old.zip` and `new.zip`. The only difference is that when I created old zip using winrar, I checked legacy encryption. You can see the picture below.

[image]

My code works for old zip, but not new.zip. Is there any other way to extract the `new.zip` file?

edit: change title from using javascript => in Node js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unzipping a password protected file in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926927/unzipping-a-password-protected-file-in-node-js)

Comment: @Vukky apparently not. unzip has some issue with node 12, see https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip/issues/122. and using unzipper didnt help since it only works on legacy encrypted zip