# create and download CSV file using javascript and add password protection on file open after download

Tags: javascript, blob, file-security

I want to add password protection on CSV file which I have just created by javascript Blob

```
new Blob([csvFile], {
  type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'
})
```

It should ask for password when user try to open that file.

How can I do that using client side javascript?

Thanks

Comment: I have also searched over an internet there is not any built-in feature from `Blob ` itself

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687992/how-can-i-make-it-csv-file-password-protected-using-javascript