# How to export password protected Excel file from html in javascripts

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am able to export Excel file from html table using JavaScript in my ASP.NET MVC project. Now I want excel file will be password protected. Can I do this using javaScripts or C#.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the password property of the workbook object.

See this, [Implementing Password Security on Excel Workbooks Using Visual Studio .NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14243/Implementing-Password-Security-on-Excel-Workbooks).

You will need to do a translation from the vb.net code to C#.

Comment: I want to implement it during the generate excel from html. Is it possible to do this in javaScripts.

Comment: @MuhammadJahidHasan I dont think that is possible. You can refer this [Make CSV Password Protected using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687992/how-can-i-make-it-csv-file-password-protected-using-javascript)