# how to convert multiple files to compressed zip file using node js

Tags: node.js, zip

I want to convert multiple files to a compressed zip file on node.js.

I tried the following code:

```
var archiver = require('archiver');
var fs = require('fs');
var StringStream = require('string-stream');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var dl = archiver('data');
    dl.pipe(response);
    dl.append(new fs.createReadStream('test/fixtures/test.txt'), {
        name: 'stream.txt', date: testDate2
    });
    dl.append(new StringStream("Ooh dynamic stuff!"), {
        name : 'YoDog/dynamic.txt'
    });
    dl.finalize(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(200000)
    });
}).listen(3500);
```

Comment: i'm not getting above code so pls tell me examples which are user friendly to understand

Comment: Have a look [at this example](https://github.com/ctalkington/node-archiver/blob/master/examples/pack-zip.js). It works for me.

Comment: is this code will alow multiple files and zip those?

Comment: It will compress multiple files to a .zip, yes.

Comment: hi mutil having doubt in the example in the above link i dint understand what is example-output.zip in  var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/example-output.zip'); pls explain me if possible

Comment: and getting error as ENOENT  app crashed waiting for file changes before starting

Comment: `example-output.zip` is the name of the zip file you will get after compression. `ENOENT` error means that the specified files (fixtures/file1.txt & fixtures/file2.txt) were not found. Change `var file1` and `var file2` to the path of the files you want to compress.

Comment: mutil had got the zip file thank you still having some doubt

Comment: if i use __dirname + "filename" it shows to directory path and i need to put those file to specific path but i dont want to do that i want the to give the path dirictly

Answer (score 26):

There is a much simpler solution with the [`archiver`](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver) module:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var archiver = require('archiver');
var output = fs.createWriteStream('./example.zip');
var archive = archiver('zip', {
    gzip: true,
    zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
});

archive.on('error', function(err) {
  throw err;
});

// pipe archive data to the output file
archive.pipe(output);

// append files
archive.file('/path/to/file0.txt', {name: 'file0-or-change-this-whatever.txt'});
archive.file('/path/to/README.md', {name: 'foobar.md'});

// wait for streams to complete
archive.finalize();
```

It also supports `tar` archives, just replace 'zip' by 'tar' at line 4.

I get no credit for this code, it's just part of the [README](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver) (you should check it out for other means of adding stuff into the archive).

Neat package, and it's probably the only one that's still being maintained and documented properly.

Comment: i am also doing like this but it will throws an error like queue closed at archive.file...I dont know why it will occur so pls tell the answer

Comment: Open a new question with your code + error stack. You can share the link here, i'll have a look

Comment: ya sure i am already raised that question..Here the link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55001614/why-queue-closed-error-occours-at-archiver-file-in-nodejs

Comment: The answer provided by Leonardo in your post is correct, this is a simple async issue.

Comment: I'm confused by archiver [readme](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver) which 1) places `archive.pipe(output)` *before* appending files and `archive.finalize()` (shouldn't it be *afterwards*?), 2) calls `archive.finalize()` as if multiple `archive.file()` operations are synchronous and it will just wait for them to finish, 3) has `end` and `close` handlers on the writeable `output` stream.   Questions:  Are the `archive.file()` operations actually synchronous?   Does `archive.finalize()` trigger `archive.pipe(output)`?  How does `archive` know when no more files are going to be added?

Answer (score 4):

For zipping up multiple files, you can use this utility method I wrote with the archiver module:-

```
var zipLogs = function(working_directory) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');
    var output = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(working_directory, 'logs.zip'));
    var archiver =  require('archiver');
    var zipArchive = archiver('zip');

    zipArchive.pipe(output);
    zipArchive.bulk([{src: [path.join(working_directory, '*.log')],  expand: true}]);
    zipArchive.finalize(function(err, bytes) {
        if (err)
            throw err;

    console.log('done:', base, bytes);
    });
}
```

This for example, zips up all the log files in a particular directory.

Answer (score -3):

To Compress the text file using node js

```
var fs=require('fs');
var Zlib=require('zlib');
fs.createReadStream('input.txt').pipe(Zlib.createGzip()).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('input.txt.gz'));
```

Comment: This only compresses one file