# Why "queue closed error" occurs at when using archiver.file module to compress files

Tags: node.js

I am trying to download multiple files as zip in nodejs using archiver. This is my code:

```
exports.downloadAllFiles = function(req,res){
    var archive = archiver('zip', {
        gzip: true,
        zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
    });
    var output = fs.createWriteStream( "/home/files/Downloads/demo.zip");

    archive.pipe(output);

    demoDb.findOne({ caseguid: req.params.id }, function(err, data) { 
        if (err) {
            res.json(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, {});
        } else {
            if(data){
                data.Files.forEach(function(singleDoc){
                       archive.append(fs.createReadStream(singleDoc.filePath), { name: singleDoc.fileName })

                })

            }

         }

    })
    archive.finalize();
};
```

This is the error stack:

```
{ Error: queue closed
    at Archiver.append (/home/node_modules/archiver/lib/core.js:552:24)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/server/controllers/caseController.js:1722:25)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Promise.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Promise.emit (/home/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/home/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
    at /home/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1406:13
    at model.Document.init (/home/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:254:11)
    at completeOne (/home/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1404:10)
    at Immediate.cb (/home/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1158:11)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/homenode_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:137:16)
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5) message: 'queue closed', code: 'QUEUECLOSED', data: undefined }
```

Comment: The answer from Leonardo looks correct, add some prints next to `archive.finalize` and `archive.append` and you will see that `finalize` is called first, which is not what you want. This is basic JS async behavior, you should learn the basics first it will make your life easier, there are plenty of tutorials online

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably the line archive.finalize() is being executed before your callback be completed. Try to move your archive.finalize to inside your callback.