# Discord.JS voice Recording and Data Compression

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently making a Discord bot that has a "User Recording" feature, and I was in a VC testing it, and kind of noticed that the output `.pcm` file was ~20GB after 13 minutes.

```js
        this.voiceChannel = await message.member.voice.channel.join()
        this.reciever = this.voiceChannel.receiver
        this.voiceChannel.on('debug', (debug) => {
            let packet = JSON.parse(debug.slice(8))
            console.log(packet.op)

            if(!packet.d || packet.d && packet.d.speaking != 1) return;
            let user = this.client.users.resolve(packet.d.user_id)
            if(packet.d.speaking) {
                let userStream = this.reciever.createStream(user, {mode: 'pcm', end: 'manual'})
                let writeStream = require('fs').createWriteStream('./recording.pcm', {})
                this.us = userStream
                this.ws = writeStream

                this.us.on("data", (chunk) =>{
                    console.log(chunk)
                    this.us.pipe(this.ws)
                })
                this.ws.on("pipe", console.log)
            }
        })
```

Is there any way possible to compress the `.pcm` file from.. I dunno, 20GB down to 5-10 MB? This seems odd as each `Buffer` that comes from Discord.js is a whopping 4000 bytes (4KB)
(This also had my Disk capped out at 100% and writing at 60MB/s)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43829712/13176517

Comment: @Syntle It wasn't putting a file into a zip/compressed folder. It was more of compressing the data on receive, and putting the compressed data in the file itself. None of the less, that link did help me dig deeper into modules of the same, and helped out.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to answer my own question, but I believe I know what I did wrong.

```js
this.us.on("data", (chunk) =>{
    console.log(chunk)
    this.us.pipe(this.ws)
})
```

I was incorrect in that section, because I was sending data whenever data was received, not once, but twice. I also used the `zlib` module (https://npmjs.org/package/zlib) and that helped even more with Data / Voice Compression.

```js
this.us.on("data", (chunk) => {
    let slowBuf = this.zlib.deflate(chunk, (er, res) => {
        console.log(res)
        this.ws.write(res)
    })
})
```

That worked like a charm and is now writing data at 600KB per 2 minutes or so of testing.