# zip the folder using built-in modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, tar, zlib

**Edit** -> Can someone suggest edits to my answer, for instance I'm not sure if `exec` is better or `spawn`?

---

Is it possible to zip the directory/folder with it's contents using [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) and other built-in modules?

I'm looking for a way to do it without external dependencies.

The other option is to run local processes on mac, windows etc. for zip, tar etc., I'm sure there are command line utilities on either of the operating system

[This is not an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754153/zip-archives-in-node-js) but it's somehow related to what I'm looking for, it's spawning a local process to zip.

Another [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/26t7mx/how_to_extract_a_zip_file_with_child_process/) I'm looking at.

[Unix command for zip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/how-do-i-zip-unzip-on-the-unix-command-line) | [exec and spawn](http://www.hacksparrow.com/difference-between-spawn-and-exec-of-node-js-child_process.html)

The commands I tried on terminal which worked,

1. /usr/bin/zip test.zip /resources/html/article
2. du -hs test.zip

Code

```
var zip = function(path) {
    const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec("which zip", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            exec(stdout + " -r " + path + "/test.zip " + path, function(error, stdout, stderr){
                if(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    exec("du -hs test.zip", function(error, stdout, stderr){
                        console.log('done');
                        console.log(arguments);
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: I don't have a starting point yet, I'm looking at codes that can help me to write some. See a linked question as an attempt

Comment: The documentation provides examples, yes?

Comment: I'm able to do it on command line but not working on nodejs, editing my latest code

Comment: Were any errors logged?

Comment: no errors, just waiting...

Comment: turns out the problem is with `which zip` command, there was a `\n` in `stdout`, removed using `trim`, it works now but wondering where does it save the zip file by default

Comment: What do you mean by _"where does it save the zip file by default"_? `pwd`? See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: location of test.zip since I didn't specify any location, I'm checking the paths where node interpreter lives...

Comment: File would not be saved to current working directory at `nodejs`?

Comment: ok, found it, I was running it in web storm, it saved in the root of directory, will be posting my answer shortly.

Comment: I've a query how can I set a base bath for zip to work on, for instance when I send this function a path of `/a/b/c/d/e/f` and when I extract I see all those folders (a-f), but instead I want the CLI to goto `/a/b/c` and then zip `/d/e/f`, I've tried `cd /a/b/c` before the zip command but then zip has errors reaching to the `/d/e/f`, basically my working directory is not changing.

Comment: turns out I've to chain both commands in one line, "cd /a/b/c && /usr/bin/zip test.zip /d/e/f`

Comment: `zip -r test.zip *` included only folders, files in current working directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on mac and works. Can someone test this on Linux? Any ideas for windows?

Notice the use of `stdout.trim()` to get rid of an extra `\n` character returned from console.

```
function execute(command) {
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){
            if(error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                stderr ? reject(stderr) : resolve(stdout.trim());
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Function zip**

```
var zip = function(path) {
    execute("which zip")
        .then(function(zip){
            return execute(zip  + " -r abc.zip " + path);
        })
        .then(function(result){
            return execute("du -hs abc.zip");
        })
        .then(function(result){
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
};
```

Comment: Four years late, but I can confirm that this works on linux... (manjaro)

Answer (score 0):

**The simplest and popular method is - child_process exec to execute commands **

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

const ls = exec(`tar -czvf filename.tar.gz dirPathToZip && mv fileName.tar.gz  moveZipFileToPath`);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
   console.log(`stdout: ${data}`)
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
   console.error(`stderr: ${data}`)
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
   fs.rmdirSync(pathDoDeleteDir, { recursive: true })
})
```